# T(n) = T(n-1) +3n^2 - 2n +1

Tags: recursion

I was wondering how do I solve this, I've been trying any possible way to but I've failed:
$$\begin{align*} T(n) &= T(n-1) +3n^2 - 2n +1 ,& n \ge 1 \\
T(0) &=2 &\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Let $a(n)$ be a sequence of numbers. Then, 

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \left[a(n) - a(n-1)\right] =  a(N) - a(0).$$